# use selected value as table name in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i've serarched for the answer, but did't find.

so i've got a table `types`

```
CREATE TABLE types
(
  type_id serial NOT NULL,
  type_name character varying,
  CONSTRAINT un_type_name UNIQUE (type_name)
)
```

which holds type names, lets say `users` - and this is the name of corresponding table `users`. this design may be a bit ugly, but it was made to allow users create their own types. (is there better way to acheve this?)

now i want to perform a query like this one:

```
select type_name, (select count(*) from ???) from types
```

to get list of all type names and count of objects of each type.

can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have enough information, but I do suspect that something is off with your design. You shouldn't need an extra table for every type.

Be that as it may, what you want to do cannot be done - in pure SQL.
It can be done with a plpgsql function executing dynamic SQL, though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_type_ct()
  RETURNS TABLE (type_name text, ct bigint) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    tbl     text;
BEGIN
    FOR tbl IN SELECT t.type_name FROM types t ORDER BY t.type_name
    LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
        'SELECT $1, count(*) FROM ' || tbl::regclass
        USING tbl;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_type_ct();
```

You'll need to study most of the [chapter about plpgsql in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) to understand what's going on here.

One special hint: the [cast to `regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) is a safeguard against SQLi. You could also use the more generally applicable `quote_ident()` for that, but that does not properly handle schema-qualified table names, while the cast to `regclass` does. It also only accepts table names that are visible to the calling user.

Comment: great! i understand whats going on in this function :) i thought i could do this without functions. **extra table for every type** is needed for performance reasons - small tables can be indexed more effective afaik

Comment: @k102: BTW, indexes work just fine with big (or huge) tables. That's what they are built for. With small tables, sequential reads are often faster than using indexes at all.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do it directly in SQL

You can use a PLpgSQL function and dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tables_count(OUT type_name character varying, OUT rows bigint)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR tables_count.type_name IN SELECT types.type_name FROM types
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || quote_ident(tables_count.type_name) INTO tables_count.rows;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM tables_count();
```

Comment: Ha, Pavel, you stole my thunder! Did not expect anybody else answering so soon. :) Obviously, I like your solution. You can tell that from what I came up with. Two small things: you were missing an `OUT` in the declaration and `type_name` is declared `character varying` which will raise an exception with your declared OUT parameter of type `text`. I fixed both.

Comment: thanks! i knew (or thought i knew) i can do it in plpgsql, i just thought how can it be done without it