# How to use values at table name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use values for joining table or schema name.

```
with country_information(region, country, lang) as (
  values ('NA', 'US', 'en'), ('EU', 'FR', 'fr'), ('EU', 'IT', 'it'))
select *
from US_data.result as r
left join US_data.promotion as p on r.id = p.id
union all
select *
from EU_data.result as r
left join EU_data.promotion as p on r.id = p.id
```

In this situation, I want to use a country_information values for joining a table.

e.g

**from {country}_data.result as r @country = country_information.country in ('NA')**

Just... imagine like this.. I don't know how to do it so It's just example.

Is there any way for using table name with user values?

Comment: It is not possible to do this in plain SQL. All table names must be known at time when query executes. 

What you can do is to use pgPlsql function and make dynamic SQL query in it based on country input parameter and then call that function in your query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use selected value as table name in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124844/use-selected-value-as-table-name-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions) like table and join with CTE data.

```sql
with country_information(region, country, lang) as (
    values ('NA', 'US', 'en'), ('EU', 'FR', 'fr'), ('EU', 'IT', 'it'))
select *
from US_data.result as r
         left join US_data.promotion as p on r.id = p.id
         left join country_information as ci on r.country = ci.country
union all
select *
from EU_data.result as r
         left join EU_data.promotion as p on r.id = p.id
         left join country_information as ci on r.country = ci.country
```

Or change above query like that and build sample query to remove duplicate join:

```sql
with country_information(region, country, lang) as (
    values ('NA', 'US', 'en'), ('EU', 'FR', 'fr'), ('EU', 'IT', 'it')
),
     data as (select *
              from US_data.result as r
                       left join US_data.promotion as p on r.id = p.id
              union all
              select *
              from EU_data.result as r
                       left join EU_data.promotion as p on r.id = p.id)
select * from data d left join country_information as ci on d.country = ci.country
```

Answer (score 0):

Use VALUES as derived table and ALIAS:

```sql
select  qq.w, qq.e from (values (1, 2), (3, 4)) as qq(w,e)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html